# Eclipse SWT ImageData getPixel returns different values on Windows vs Mac OSX

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp

I'm having some problems with transparency.

I'm using the snippet provided in https://stackoverflow.com/a/27453793, but while on Windows it works, on Mac it does not.

On further investigation the different appears to be the value returned from `getPixel`.

Take the below example, using a 1x1 pixel transparent image I created.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;

import org.eclipse.jface.resource.ImageDescriptor;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.ImageData;

public class ImageTest {
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    try (InputStream stream = new URL("https://i.imgur.com/BFlkniE.png").openStream()) {
        final Path path = Files.createTempFile(null, ".png");
        Files.copy(stream, path, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

        final ImageDescriptor element = ImageDescriptor.createFromFile(null, path.toString());

        final Image image = element.createImage();
        final ImageData imageData = image.getImageData();

        System.out.println(imageData.getPixel(0, 0));
    }
    }
}
```

On Windows, the output is 0, on Mac it's 16711680. What's the reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

The value returned by `ImageData.getPixel` is not necessarily a RGB value, it is just a value for the current colour table. You must use the `PaletteData` in the `ImageData` to get the RGB value:

```java
RGB rgb = imageData.palette.getRGB(imageData.getPixel(0, 0));
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply - using the above I still get a difference in behaviour between the two platforms (RGB {0, 0, 0} vs RGB {255, 255, 255}).

Plus (and I appreciate this wasn't my original problem), you can see that ultimately I'd like to use this to set the `imageData.transparentPixel`, which is an `int`.

Comment: I am using macOS and get  zeros although I can reproduce the FFs by using `ImageDescriptor.createFromURL`.  Not sure what is happening.

Comment: I think I get the inverse behaviour on Windows (i.e. Windows then shows 255, Mac 0) but they are still different.

I'll take `Not sure what is happening` as a sign I'm not going crazy.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you open an `InputStream` and then you proceed to completely ignore it and create your `ImageDescriptor` from a temp file instead.

According to the documentation of `Files.createTempFile()`, this temp file is empty, so trying to create an image from it is guaranteed to fail, no matter what your operating system is.

Apparently the implementation of `ImageDescriptor.createFromFile()` behaves differently between the two operating systems in the erroneous situation of trying to read an image from an empty file.

I suppose what is happening is that in both cases they are trying to act in a supposedly error-tolerant way, failing silently instead of throwing an exception.  However, the underlying operating systems apparently fail slightly differently, so the initialization of `ImageDescriptor` ends up being incomplete in different ways.

If it appears to you that it is working under Windows, then this is either due to pure coincidence, or, more likely, you are not determining correctly whether it fails or not. You appear to regard that the zero pixel value returned under windows indicates success; I would not be so sure about that.

Comment: Thankyou for your reply. You are correct there's an error in the code I originally posted (now fixed) - but this isn't my problem, that was simply an accident when simplifying the code to post the question.

I've edited it to better reflect the scenario. I wasn't assuming 0 was a valid return value - rather I was simply noting a difference in behaviour.